# vb.net scrollable content panel

Tags: vb.net, controls

Is there a control in vb.net that is specifically designed for displaying content larger than the control itself?

I know it's possible to code your own using a panel and two scrollbars, but is there an already existing method for this?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, the Panel class, it's on the toolbox.  Set AutoScroll = True or the AutoScrollMinSize property if you have to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All control containers, such as `Panel`, `FlowLayoutPanel` etc. have `AutoScroll` property, which does what you want.